# How to make a Python PyQT program not open the command line in Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a Python program that is mostly complete, and there is one thing that I'd like to change, which may or may not be possible.

This program uses PyQT to display a GUI and I have it pretty much pinned up so I was wondering if I can make Python not open up a termianl when I open the program.

I am using Windows XP right now, but the machines it will run on will be Windows 7.  I generally work with Linux, so I'm not terribly familiar with Windows.

If the terminal has to be there, it's no big deal, but I feel like it's extraneous at this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the python extension .pyw.

E.g program.pyw

This causes your program to be run with pythonw.exe instead of python.exe which suppresses the terminal.